# Помогите, код наполовину не работает: открывается файл, но обратно не закрывается(открываю и закрываю с помощью модуля os )

Tags: python, ос

```
import os, time
a = input('Программа: ')
os.startfile(a)
time.sleep(10)
os.system(f"taskkill /IM {a} /F")
```

открывается, но не закрывается, что делать?

Comment: Посмотрите как работает команда `taskkill` в командной строке.

Answer (score 0):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3 

import os
import sys 
import subprocess
import time 


message = 'Programm -> '
filename = input(message)


def open_file(filename: str):
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        os.startfile(filename)
    else:
        opener = "open" if sys.platform == "darwin" else "xdg-open"
        subprocess.call([opener, filename])



def forced_termination(process_name: str) -> None:
    try:
        time.sleep(10)
        os.system('taskkill /IM "' + process_name + '" /F')
    except TimeoutError as err:
        print(err)
```

есть библиотека https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#
она как раз для работы с тасками в винде.